# How to create multiple layouts using MarionetteJS?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I have my backbone marionette and requireJS application structured in different folders: collections, controllers, config, init, models, routers, services, templates and views.

There is one region called mainRegion defined in the AppInit file. 
How should I change the views I am using in the mainRegion?

One option is having a Layout with two regions like header and content in the mainRegion using Marionette Layouts.

Where should I create my layout? 
In the views folder or controller folder or any thing else?

Comment: Did my answer help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion of creating a Layout is perfectly valid.

Here's another option. The Marionette Application is alot like a Layout [with support for multiple regions](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#regions-and-the-application-object)
so you could define your application like this:

```
App.addRegions({
  header: "#header",
  main: "#main"
});
```

If `main` is very complex, it can be a layout also with nested regions. For example,
if you have a sidebar, content, and footer, it could be arranged like this:

```
app                 -> Marionette.Application
  header              -> Marionette.Region
  main                -> Marionette.Region
    mainLayout          -> Marionette.Layout
      sidebar             -> Marionette.Region
      content             -> Marionette.Region
      footer              -> Marionette.Region
```

After showing your views it would look like this:

```
app                 -> Marionette.Application
  header              -> Marionette.Region
    headerContent       -> YourHeaderViewClass
  main                -> Marionette.Region
    mainLayout          -> Marionette.Layout
      sidebar             -> Marionette.Region
        sidebarContent      -> YourSidebarView
      content             -> Marionette.Region
        appContent          -> YourAppContentView
      footer              -> Marionette.Region
        footerContent       -> YourFooterView
```

---

Regarding organization, Layouts are a kind of view, so I sometimes place them in my `views` folder.

However, if I end up with many layouts I'll create another folder next to
`views` called `layouts` and organize them separately

```
...
views/
  viewA.js
  viewB.js
layouts/
  mainLayout.js
  otherLayout.js
...
```